# How to change URL in protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I'm wondering how do you change the current URL upon pressing some button or link.

```
browser.waitForAngular();
expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.match(/document/).and.notify(callback);
```

I know this code will get the url and match it with document, I would like to set the URL upon a click.

e.g. I'm on Facebook and I want to go to profile, I click Profile button but want to update the URL by parsing a string value to it rather than a class/function

As I have a piece of code that doesn't have any classes to point to, the only thing I have is a href which contains the path location to the page.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `browser.get()` or `browser.driver.get()`?http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't actually let the browser navigate to the new URL on click, get it via [`browser.getCurrentUrl()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl), modify it and navigate to the modified URL, e.g.

```
button.click();

browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
    browser.get(url + "?a=b");
});
```

Comment: browser.getCurrentUrl() is async, so you probably need to use .then()

Comment: @BartekS oh man, I don't even remember answering here :) Thanks for heads up, fixed.